# Ring homomorphism with isomorphism under addition gives Ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

If there is a ring homomorphism that is also an isomorphism for the underlying additive group, is it a ring isomorphism? And is this essentially just saying that when the map is closed under multiplication, the ring inherits its isomorphism from the underlying additive group?

It must be true, since the map is bijective over the sets; but it seems a bit too simple and I can't help but think I am missing a detail.

Comment: A ring isomorphism is a ring homomorphism that is bijective on underlying sets. A group isomorphism is necessarily bijective. So if you have a ring homomorphism that is a group isomorphism, then...

Comment: "Closed under multiplication" is a property of subsets of a ring, not of functions. Morphisms are multiplicative (or "respect multiplication"), they aren't "closed under multiplication".

Comment: Indeed, I was almost convinced that there was nothing interesting going on (besides what it true) but I needed to be certain. Thanks, also, for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with groups,  it suffices to say that a ring homomorphism is injective.   Then in either category, **Grp** or **Ring**,  you get an isomorphism onto the image.

As an isomorphism on the underlying group of a ring is necessarily bijective,  the answer is yes.